# Ember 2.2 relationships always null

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Can't seem to figure out why my relationships are always null.

app/models/group.js

```
export default Model.extend({
    originalID: DS.attr('number'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    slideshows: DS.hasMany('slideshow', { async: true }),
});
```

app/models/slideshow.js

```
export default Model.extend({
    originalID: DS.attr('number'),
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    group: DS.belongsTo('group', { async: true }),
});
```

Creating some data:

```
group = self.store.createRecord('group', {
    originalID: 100,
    name: 'Fake Group'
});

group.save();

slideshow = self.store.createRecord('slideshow', {
    originalID: 101,
    title: 'Fake Slideshow',
    group: group
});

slideshow.save();
```

When I view the document in Pouch DB inspector group is always null. I'm following the guide on Ember's documentation page but it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: You're not waiting for `group` to save before creating the slideshow, that might be the problem.

Comment: That was it if you want to answer the question I'll mark it.

Comment: Posted as an answer with a code sample ;)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: No problem, your question coincided with my daily check in!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`group.save()` is an asynchronous operation, so you need to guarantee that it's finished before proceeding with the rest. Something like so should work:

```
group.save().then(g => {
  let slideshow = this.store.createRecord('slideshow', {
    originalID: 101,
    title: 'Fake Slideshow',
    group: g
  });

  slideshow.save();
});
```